# Post two array as json through ajax to Spring Controller

Tags: ajax, json, spring

My ajax method

$.ajax(
            {

```
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType:'json',
            url: 'addrequisition',
            data: JSON.stringify([{ ids: val, qty: valtxt }]),
            success: function(result)
            {
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

and my arrays are val and valtxt.
I want to read those arrays in a Spring Controller help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define a class in java like this:

```
class MyClass{
private String ids;
private String qty;
//Setters and Getters

 }
```

Note that the members of class MUST be same as json data.
then in your controller you need to define action like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addrequisition", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addrequisition(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {

    String result = myClass.getIds() + myClass.getQty();
    return result;
}
```